# How do I get a notice number to pay North Carolina income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, online-payment, north-carolina

This page says I can pay my North Carolina individual income tax using the online payment system: https://www.ncdor.gov/taxes-forms/collections-past-due-taxes/payment-options

But the online payment system requires a notice number: https://eservices.dor.nc.gov/ofp/validation.jsp

I don't have a notice number. I'm just trying to pay my state taxes. It looks like I only get a notice number if I'm sent a bill, like if I'm late in paying my taxes: https://eservices.dor.nc.gov/ofp/epay_help.html#noticeNumberLocate

So how do I get a notice number for paying my individual income tax on time? Or do I not need one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL you included in your question:

https://www.ncdor.gov/taxes-forms/collections-past-due-taxes/payment-options

even includes the phrase:

```
collections-past-due
```

you should be looking at the section of the state website:

https://www.ncdor.gov/file-pay

for information regarding how to pay your taxes.

Comment: All right, thank you. I was eventually able to find this link for paying my taxes: https://eservices.dor.nc.gov/d400v/d400vContact.jsp